# HTML/CSS - How would I center the name link in this div?

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to leave the image alone and center the name "Tim Heidecker" in this div..
http://jsfiddle.net/4huq3/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Center horizontally, vertically, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/4huq3/24/

```
#left {
    width: 228px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#left a{line-height:60px}

.icon {
    vertical-align:middle

}
```

Comment: Nice, except for the line before Tim.

Comment: Here an update without the line before Tim: http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/4huq3/46/

Answer (score 0):

try adding `vertical-align:middle;` to your `.icon` rule

Answer (score 0):

What I did was add an id to the  tag with the name link, then position it. See this forked jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/98RhD/10/

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="left"><a href="..." class="icon"><span>Time Heidecker</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
#left { position: relative; width: 228px; height: 60px; border: 1px solid #000; }
#left span { position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 70px; }
```

You'll have to fiddle with the numbers to get exactly your final center position according to the size of the text and final box and / or if you want vertical centering (CSS Top) or horizontal centering (CSS Left).

I hope this helps!